# Android ListView with Fragment

Tags: android, listview

I'm working on my school project which is based on a Fragment. I have made the XML files but I'm getting an error in the nearfragment.java. Could you please tell me where the error is as I'm familiar with Activity but not with Fragment. Please help me to rectify the error.

near_layout.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="{relativePackage}.${activityClass}" >

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/list_li"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true" >
    </ListView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

near_layout_mylist.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/icon_list"
        android:layout_width="60dp"
        android:layout_height="60dp"
        android:padding="5dp" />

    <LinearLayout android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/item_list"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Medium Text"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:padding="2dp"
            android:textColor="#33CC33" />
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView1_list"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="TextView"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"/>
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

CustomListNearAdapter.java

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class CustomListNearAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String> {

    private final Activity context;
    private final String[] itemname;
    private final Integer[] imgid;

    public CustomListNearAdapter(Activity context, String[] itemname, Integer[] imgid) {
        super(context, R.layout.near_layout_mylist, itemname);
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub

        this.context=context;
        this.itemname=itemname;
        this.imgid=imgid;
    }

    public View getView(int position,View view,ViewGroup parent) {
        LayoutInflater inflater=context.getLayoutInflater();
        View rowView=inflater.inflate(R.layout.near_layout_mylist, null,true);

        TextView txtTitle = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.item_list);
        ImageView imageView = (ImageView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.icon_list);
        TextView extratxt = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.textView1_list);

        txtTitle.setText(itemname[position]);
        imageView.setImageResource(imgid[position]);
        extratxt.setText("Description "+itemname[position]);
        return rowView;

    };
}
```

NearFragment

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.GridView;
import android.widget.ListView;

/**
 * Created by Ratan on 7/29/2015.
 */
public class NearFragment extends Fragment {



    ListView list;
    String[] itemname ={
            "Safari",
            "Camera",
            "Global",
            "FireFox",
            "UC Browser",
            "Android Folder",
            "VLC Player",
            "Cold War"
    };

    Integer[] imgid={
            R.drawable.akash,
            R.drawable.akash,
            R.drawable.akash,
            R.drawable.akash,
            R.drawable.akash,
            R.drawable.akash,
            R.drawable.akash,
            R.drawable.akash,
    };

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.near_layout, container,false);
        CustomListNearAdapter adapter=new CustomListNearAdapter(this, itemname, imgid);

        ListView listView = (ListView) view.findViewById(R.id.list_item);
        listView.setAdapter(new CustomListNearAdapter(getActivity()));
        return view;


    }


}
```

The error lies in nearfragment, I'm not able to write the code for the Fragment. So please give me some directions.

Comment: :Akashdeep Singh: what is the error? and post logcat .

Comment: Instead of the this, why are you not using 'getActivity()'

Comment: for `CustomListNearAdapter` shouldn't you be using the constructor with all of the items? Activity, item name, and image?

Comment: Please post your LOGCAT.

Comment: logcat not necessary as the error lies in nearfragment code. Just need to write it for the fragment

Comment: I would invite you to post the error you are having. I would also ask you why are you creating the CustomNearListAdapter twice, once before initializing the ListView and once when calling setAdapter ?
Also, you cannot call getActivity() in onCreateView because the Activity might not yet be created at this point. Usually I set adapters into the onActivityCreated method.

Comment: Repcale your code like this. 
listView.setAdapter(new CustomListNearAdapter(getActivity(),itemname, imgid));

and remove this line. 
CustomListNearAdapter adapter=new CustomListNearAdapter(this, itemname, imgid);

Comment: Please follow my answer. It solves it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In yours code you are not passing the correct values to the constructor while setting the `adapter` , means at the line in yours code.

```
listView.setAdapter(new CustomListNearAdapter(getActivity()));
```

In above line there is problem, so replace the code with below lines of code.

```
        CustomListNearAdapter adapter=new CustomListNearAdapter(getActivity(), itemname, imgid);

        ListView listView = (ListView) view.findViewById(R.id.list_li);
        listView.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Comment: erros removed but the app crashed

Comment: @AkashdeepSingh.. what crash  are you getting..pleasse let me konw

Comment: Please refer to my answer. You have to use `onActivityCreated` for `ListView`. This answer is incomplete.

Comment: @AkashdeepSingh You are getting the eexception because in your XML , you are using the list_li and in the code you find the id of listview by these name list_item....So i have edited my answer , so please check and let me know in case of concern

Comment: @KVISH...DId u down-vote ,  my answer... If there is any other error than , plz let me know..

Comment: @AkashdeepSingh ...Happy to help bro :) plz accept it also :P

Comment: @RavindraKushwaha is der anyway i can contact you directly

Comment: @AkashdeepSingh ...First of all plz remove the error POST from the answer..and upadate it into yours question..In the stackoverflow, we can not post the error logs in the answer part,So plz firstly remove it from answer part...And ,there is no another way to contact directly :( ...

Answer (score 1):

Use **getActivity()** instead of **this** in bellow line

```
CustomListNearAdapter adapter=new CustomListNearAdapter(this, itemname, imgid);
```

and set adapter to listview like bellow

```
listView.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest you write the code for the `ListView` after the activity has been loaded. So make your code like below:

```
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.near_layout, container, false);
    return view;
}

public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);

    CustomListNearAdapter adapter=new CustomListNearAdapter(getActivity(), itemname, imgid);
    ListView listView = (ListView) view.findViewById(R.id.list_item);
    listView.setAdapter(new CustomListNearAdapter(getActivity()));
}
```

The `getActivity()` may be causing issue here since the activity has not been created. Also, you weren't initializing the adapter properly. You didn't provide all values.

Answer (score 1):

Repcale your code like this.

```
 View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.near_layout, container,false);

    ListView listView = (ListView) view.findViewById(R.id.list_item);
    listView.setAdapter(new CustomListNearAdapter(getActivity(), itemname, imgid));
    return view;
```